# Minitest #setup and #teardown not called when test run via Rake

Tags: ruby, testing, minitest

I have a MiniTest suite. I'm using the basic `Minitest::Unit::TestCase`, not specs. I have `setup` and `teardown` methods defined in my `TestCase` subclass. They work perfectly when I run a test file like so: `ruby test/whatever_test.rb`. But when I run `rake test`, `setup` and `teardown` are not called. The relevant portion of my Rakefile is:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.test_files = FileList['test/*_test.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```

Why wouldn't the `setup` and `teardown` be run when `Rake::TestTask` is used?

I'd paste the test case code into here, but there's quite a lot of it. I'll certainly paste in some subset of it, if there's a particular section you'd like to see.

I'm running Minitest 4.3.2 on Ruby 1.9.3-p194.

Comment: Could you post a minimal not-working test?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem was that another test case was overwriting the `setup` and `teardown` methods. I had accidentally given two test cases the same class name, which is why the overwriting happened. Naturally, this error didn't happen when I ran a single test case, which explains the difference in behavior when using Rake.

Comment: Had this similar issue in Rails 5 System tests (which uses minitest). The setup method for a system test was not being executed when we ran all our system tests, but it was executing when we only ran that system test file.  Our fix was simply renaming the system test file to something else and that fixed the overriding that was occurring. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was writing tests for socket communication and had added a helper method named `send`. Since MiniTest uses `send` internally to call the teardown methods, it was instead calling my own `send` instead of the method-dispatch.